# SqlConnection by Method

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm trying to implement a method that will provide the `SqlConnection`, how should I do it?

```
public class DAL
{
    public bool dbCon()
    {
        string comboValue;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn =
                new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =VirtualXP-64805;Initial Catalog=CTS_Demo;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a method that opens a connection and return the instance of that connection?

Comment: Why don't use use directly built-in connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method should return the connection object not a bool value, or you may define a class level connection variable and use that.

But When it comes to Database Connection then **open it as late as possible and close it as early as possible**

Instead of opening the connection from the method you may simply return the connection object and open it where you need it. Something like:

```
public SqlConnection dbCon()
{
 return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =VirtualXP-64805;Initial Catalog=CTS_Demo;Integrated Security=SSPI");
}
```

and then where you are using it:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = dbCon())
{
  conn.Open();
  .... your code
}
```

Or you can get rid of the method and simply call the `new SqlConnection` with connection string from the configuration.

**EDIT:**

Since you want to return an open connection from your method, you can do the following, but IMO its not the recommended way, you have to call `Dispose` manually for each connection object, since you will not use it within using statement.

```
public SqlConnection dbCon()
{
 SqlConnection sqlConn;

 try
 {
   sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =VirtualXP-64805;Initial Catalog=CTS_Demo;Integrated Security=SSPI")

 }
 catch(SqlException)
 {
  //your exception handling details
  sqlConn = null;
 }
return sqlConn;

}
```

Comment: Hi Gian, yes is my answer to your question. Do you have that idea?